# Get the value of a specific variable in a html template with django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the value which is stored in a variable as :

html

```html
<p class="title" name="no">Guarde : {{no}}</p>
...
<form action="nextep" method="get">
  <button class="btright" name="btnext" action="nextep">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
</form>
```

views.py

```py
def nextep(request):
    n = {{ no }} #I would like to get it from the initial value stored (which is 1)
    return render(request, "episode.html", {'no': n+1})
```

How could I do that please? I tried different version with request.get['no'] too, but nothing worked, if someone has an idea, thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

You can create a  tag to link to a particular view and pass the value of 'no' to the view.
View:

```
def nextep(request, value):
    n = value
    return render(request, "episode.html", {'no': value+1})
```

HTML:

```
<a href={%url 'nextep' {{no}}%}>Next Step </a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wanted to know please, by using this type of url it sends me to an other template , like am I suppose to have nextbt.html ? When I print the value of no it prints me : [04/Aug/2021 09:58:53] "GET /?btnext= HTTP/1.1" 200 2251
Hence nothing changes on the page just the url as: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?btnext=

Comment: Do you want the page to reload to show the updated value of 'no'? For that instead of render, use 'redirect' and enter the 'name' of the url for that template